# Python list raw Cloudwatch Metrics values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm going throw documentation for `boto3` AWS. And cannot find simple information for fetching **raw** values from my custom metrics.

For ex. I'm trying to log user id on access for particular website path. But from the documentation I have access for aggregated values only. Which means it's impossible to do. And this static is `SampleCount'|'Average'|'Sum'|'Minimum'|'Maximum`. Which means no sense for my particular case of user id.

**UPD**

In simple words there is no support to fetch raw values from the Cloudwatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statistic you are refering to are obtained using [get_metric_statistics](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_statistics). However, to get the actual data points you should be looking at [get_metric_data](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data):

> You can use the GetMetricData API to retrieve as many as 500 different metrics in a single request, with a total of **as many as 100,800 data points**.

But it should be noted that the older the data points, the less resolution they have. AWS does not store all points. Only "new" data will be stored with original resolution.

> Data points that are initially published with a shorter period are aggregated together for long-term storage. For example, if you collect data using a period of 1 minute, the data remains available for **15 days** with 1-minute resolution. After 15 days, this data is still available, but is **aggregated** and retrievable only with a resolution of 5 minutes.

#### Update on aggregation

Also from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html):

> Although you can publish data points with time stamps as granular as one-thousandth of a second, CloudWatch **aggregates the data to a minimum granularity of 1 second**.

Comment: As you can see from the `get_metric_data` there is REQUIRED param `Stat`. Which means that response data points will be aggregated in any case. Right?

Comment: @GensaGames You can get down to 1 second period for high resolution metrics. But when you publish more points then one point in each second, they will be aggregated. I don't think AWS will store metrics with infinite resolution.

Comment: what infinitive resolution? I have 10 data points for 3 month. How do I get it's raw values? From API above `get_metric_data` has REQUIRED field of aggregation and cannot return raw values at all.

Comment: If they are not overlapping, you can use 1 min period with average stats. Average value of 1 point in each period will be equal to the actual raw value.

Comment: @Marchin. Right. So it doesn't look like support. For ex. I can put `Stat` param `Sum` and list these  points. But if I would receive these 3 points at the same day and time. It would be different aggregated value. So there is no support from Cloudwatch to list raw values, right?

Comment: @GensaGames I updated the answer. The maximum resolution is 1 second. So if you submit 3 data points at the same time (i.e. same second) they will be aggregated.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Let's just say *there is no support for raw values*. Because it's still impossible to relay on raw value(and any kind of implementation), because there are might be collision very easily.

Comment: @GensaGames No problem. Glad cloud help. You are right, technically raw data is not stored.

Answer (score 1):

CloudWatch does not store raw values published with PutMetricData, it only stores aggregations. Smallest granularity you can get is 1 sec, for the latest 3 hours.

If you need access to raw values, you could use CloudWatch Logs with Embedded Metric Format to publish your metrics: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Embedded_Metric_Format.html

That way CloudWatch Logs creates your custom metrics, which will still only have the aggregations. You can use them for alarming and dashboarding.

But you will also have the raw CloudWatch Logs entries you can look up and see what exactly was published.